# Load content in tabs when page loading is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page with some tabs. In each tab there is content. While the page is being loaded, all of the content is showing alltogether one below the other. When the page loads completely, the content is placed into the tabs respectively. I would like to show the content IN the tabs when the page will load completly and not showing on the main page while loading. After the page is 100% loaded, the TAB switching works perfectly

Below please find the code of the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabset-holder">
          <ul class="tabset">
            <li><a href="#overview" class="tab active"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#features" class="tab"><span>Features</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#screenshots" class="tab"><span>Screenshots</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#video" class="tab"><span>Video</span></a></li>             
          </ul>
        </div>
```

For example if Screenshots will be clicked, the div below will show:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="screenshots">
   <p>TEST</p>               
</div>
```

Comment: You could have a look at the framework from twitter: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ this makes such things a whole easier.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS style to your page to make the `tab-content` divs hidden on page load.

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}
```

jQueryUI will then take care of making the correct tab visible once the page is ready.

Comment: not working :/ content is being hidden, but then when I click on a tab, the content is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

hide the container using css (`display:none`),

and then show the container, on tabs load event of the jQuery-ui tabs:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#container').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax calls the first time the user clicks on not showed tabs and get their content from a server side page. Look at

```
$.ajax()
```

function on JQuery doc